# JSON response from server different than expected

Tags: php, android, json

I'm trying to create a login application on android and I get an error telling me that the JSON object is null.

I get the error from here:

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        if (json == null) {
            Log.e("JSON", "Object is null!!!");
        }
        return json;
    }
```

This is my JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    is.close();
    return sb.toString();
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        for (int i=0; i<params.size(); i++) {
            Log.v("askj",params.get(i).toString());
        }
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        try {
            Log.v("askj","HTTP Entity : " + convertStreamToString(httpPost.getEntity().getContent()));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.v("askj",json);
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

This is what I'm sending and receiving:

```
05-14 10:49:26.547  27963-28074/name.company.project V/askj﹕ tag=login
05-14 10:49:26.547  27963-28074/name.company.project V/askj﹕ email=emailTest
05-14 10:49:26.547  27963-28074/name.company.project V/askj﹕ password=passTest
05-14 10:49:26.557  27963-28074/name.company.project V/askj﹕ HTTP Entity sent : tag=login&email=emailTest&password=passTest
05-14 10:49:27.117  27963-28074/name.company.project V/askj﹕ json received: Club
    <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
    <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

And this is my index.php :

```
<?php

/**
PHP API for Login, Register, Changepassword, Resetpassword Requests and for Email Notifications.
**/

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // Get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // Include Database handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db       = new DB_Functions();
    // response Array
    $response = array(
        "tag" => $tag,
        "success" => 0,
        "error" => 0
    );

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $email    = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            // echo json with success = 1
            $response["success"]            = 1;
            $response["user"]["fname"]      = $user["firstname"];
            $response["user"]["lname"]      = $user["lastname"];
            $response["user"]["email"]      = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["uname"]      = $user["username"];
            $response["user"]["uid"]        = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"]     = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'chgpass') {
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $newpassword = $_POST['newpas'];

        $hash               = $db->hashSSHA($newpassword);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt               = $hash["salt"];
        $subject            = "Change Password Notification";
        $message            = "Hello User,nnYour Password is sucessfully changed.nnRegards,nLearn2Crack Team.";
        $from               = "contact@learn2crack.com";
        $headers            = "From:" . $from;
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {

            $user = $db->forgotPassword($email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
            if ($user) {
                $response["success"] = 1;
                mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                $response["error"] = 1;
                echo json_encode($response);
            }

            // user is already existed - error response

        } else {

            $response["error"]     = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User not exist";
            echo json_encode($response);

        }
    } else if ($tag == 'forpass') {
        $forgotpassword = $_POST['forgotpassword'];

        $randomcode = $db->random_string();

        $hash               = $db->hashSSHA($randomcode);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt               = $hash["salt"];
        $subject            = "Password Recovery";
        $message            = "Hello User,nnYour Password is sucessfully changed. Your new Password is $randomcode . Login with your new Password and change it in the User Panel.nnRegards,nLearn2Crack Team.";
        $from               = "contact@learn2crack.com";
        $headers            = "From:" . $from;
        if ($db->isUserExisted($forgotpassword)) {

            $user = $db->forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $encrypted_password, $salt);
            if ($user) {
                $response["success"] = 1;
                mail($forgotpassword, $subject, $message, $headers);
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                $response["error"] = 1;
                echo json_encode($response);
            }

            // user is already existed - error response

        } else {

            $response["error"]     = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User not exist";
            echo json_encode($response);

        }

    } else if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $fname    = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname    = $_POST['lname'];
        $email    = $_POST['email'];
        $uname    = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $subject = "Registration";
        $message = "Hello $fname,nnYou have sucessfully registered to our service.nnRegards,nAdmin.";
        $from    = "contact@learn2crack.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"]     = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else if (!$db->validEmail($email)) {
            $response["error"]     = 3;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Invalid Email Id";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"]            = 1;
                $response["user"]["fname"]      = $user["firstname"];
                $response["user"]["lname"]      = $user["lastname"];
                $response["user"]["email"]      = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["uname"]      = $user["username"];
                $response["user"]["uid"]        = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"]     = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $response["error"]     = 3;
        $response["error_msg"] = "JSON ERROR";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    echo "Club";
}
?>
```

I have 0 experience with php so I can't tell why I'm receiving that string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I no longer receive the "Hosting 24 analytics code..." because I added `exit;` at the end of my php file, but the line `if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '')` is still not true.

If I add this `print_r($_GET);` at the beginning of index.php I get in the verbose log

```
Array
    (
    )
    Club
```

. Does this mean that the php is not receiving anything at all ?

Comment: The fact that you `echo "Club";` and you received "Club" from the server tells you that the issue is on the checking of `if ($tag == 'login') {` Why don't you output some debug information on $tag before that and play with Postman?

Comment: As I said I have no experience in php. I will try to google how to debug it and get back to you.

Comment: Ok well the first thing I would do is just add an `echo $tag; die();` after `$tag = $_POST['tag'];` and test it to see what the php is pulling in.

Comment: Did as you said and nothing changes. I still get the same response and if I go straight to the website I still see only Club. If the entity is `tag=login&email=emailTest&password=passTest` does the full url look like http://sitename.com/tag=login&email=emailTest&password=passTest ? Because if I test it manually like that it gives me error404.

Comment: Apologies, due to the lack of formatting I didn't see where the issue was occuring: `(isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') ` is not calling as true which means $_POST['tag'] is not set.

Comment: So how do I solve that ? And what should the link be for that to work ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your received data:

```
Club
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

then a JSON parser will not interpret this as it's invalid, your JSON Parser will then return null `(json == null)`

From your code  at the very bottom, `echo "Club";` is not valid JSON either. I can't see where the analytics code is coming from though, have you not provided the full PHP, or maybe your host is injecting this? It should not be there, it will hinder JSON parsers as well.

Comment: That is the full code for index.php. That echo is supposed to happen as an else. The first if statement fails for some reason.

Comment: That's fine but you still need to return some sort of JSON, even if it's just `{"result":"Club"}` or `json_encode(array("result" => "Club")` as otherwise your JSON parser will return null due to invalid JSON.

Comment: You'll also need to track down the source of the analytics code, it will interfere with the parser. It also won't gather any analytics for your app as the javascript won't be running.

Comment: yeah,but I don't want the else statement to return anything. I'll test the php now to see why the if statement fails

Comment: Worthwhile adding `print_r($_POST)` to the top of your PHP file, then view the output data in the same log to confirm all the values are getting there.

Comment: Did as you said and now I'm getting this before what I usually get: `Array
    (
    )`

Comment: Can you try `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: I get the same response :D

Answer (score 0):

> If I add this print_r($_GET); at the beginning of index.php I get in
>   the verbose log

You are not using `GET` you are using `POST`, so it should be `print_r($_POST);`.

If you are not sure then use `print_r($_REQUEST);`

You also echo all over your script I suggest you to build your array the way you did and only echo at the end of your script before `exit;`

And don't echo `club` instead return a `JSON` formatted message, so that your android app don't crash when trying to parse.

Also where did you define `login_tag`, `if (isset($_POST['tag']))` should be enough to check if the post variable is set.

Comment: I used `print_r($_POST);` too and I get the same response.Well the else should never be executed when sending from the app.

Comment: What should I modify in the app/server code to make it work ?

Comment: @BogdanDaniel you just need better debugging skills, to debug this remove everything and put `<?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST);?>` then log the response to your android app

Comment: I know ... As I said there I don't have experience with php. Thank you for helping me. I did as you said and the response that I get is `[]`.

Comment: This means the app is not sending the post variables successfully, I need to see more

Comment: What else can I do to help you ?

Comment: I see in your android logs the values are set right

Comment: Yes, so the problem must come from somewhere else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77813/discussion-between-meda-and-bogdan-daniel).